# Remove .pyc files from Git remote repository

Tags: git, pyc

Accidentally, I have pushed the .pyc files to the master repository. Now I want to delete them but I can´t do it. Is there any way to remove them directly from the Bitbucket site?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

1. **Remove** `.pyc` files using `git rm *.pyc`. If this not work use `git rm -f *.pyc`
2. **Commit** `git commit -a -m 'all pyc files removed'`
3. **Push** `git push`
4. In future commits you can ignore `.pyc` files by creating a `.gitignore` file

Comment: In addition to the fourth point: You **can** use [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/api/python), but double check the entries.

Comment: _Additional info about .gitignore file_ content ,add this line `*.pyc`  in your .gitignore to ignore every .pycin future after removing as stated above

Comment: and indeed adding it to .gitignore will help in future.

Comment: if your using zsh and it says it can't find any files ending in .pyc add `unsetopt nomatch` in your zshrc.

Comment: In zsh we should use double quotation: `git rm "*.pyc"`

Answer (score 26):

No, you cannot delete them directly from the BitBucket interface but you *can* delete them in your local checkout and `find ./ -type f -name '*.pyc' -exec git rm {} \;` ( or simply git rm each pyc file one by one ). Then commit/push your changes.

Finally, to avoid ever making the same mistake again you may create a file at the root of your repo and name it '.gitignore' with the contents:

```
*.pyc
*~
*.swp
```

*~ and ~.swp are other commonly forgotten file types that are often accidentally pushed. See the github doc on gitignore https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files (and their repo of .gitignore files for some nice defaults).

Answer (score 24):

This works for me,

```
find . -name '*.pyc' | xargs -n 1 git rm --cached
```

Comment: This works better than the accepted solution for .pyc files which are in subdirectories

Answer (score 23):

```
git rm *.pyc --cached
git commit -a -m'remove pyc from index'
git push
```

PS: I see the date of question, but this solution looks better, imho. May be it'll help someone.. .

Comment: I get "On branch dev nothing to commit, working tree clean" even though these files were in my repo and they are not in gitignore file

Answer (score 4):

I used simeg's solution but also wanted to deleted tons of *.pyc files added by mistake to a branch. I used awk to delete them from cache recursively.

```
git status | awk '{if($1=="modified:" && $2!=".gitignore") ; system("git rm --cached "$2)}'
```

Then, I deleted the files from my local

```
find . -name *.pyc -delete
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove all `.pyc` files use `git rm -rf *.pyc`

Then add the `*.py[co]` to your **.gitignore** file. (This will prevent .pyc and .pyo files from getting committed in the future commits)

Answer (score 1):

Because in default Bitbucket, there is no .gitignore file in the repo,so you can do :

1. you can create local .gitignore(should not be pushed) and add *.pyc as a line;
2. you can copy the .gitignore in Github repo and add *.pyc as a line in this file! You can push it or keep it in your local repo!

Answer (score 1):

### Quick way with **PyDev for eclipse**.

Go to the PyDev Package Explorer of your project and do:

---

- **right click** + **Pydev** / **Remove *.pyc *.pyo and *$py.class File**

  > a window will popup telling you how many files have been deleted.

Optional: Commit your change to the team/server:

- **right click** + **team / commit**

In the commit window you shouldn't see any .pyc available to add as we deleted them.
Also if you committed such files before then you should be able to commit their "deletion" now.

===>  Your local and server repository are now free of *.pyc *.pyo and *$py.class File :)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner for fun:

`git status | grep pyc | sed -e 's/    new file:   //g' | xargs -I {} git rm --cached {}`

Answer (score 0):

another liner for fun to remove all the pyc files.

find . -name '*.pyc' -exec git rm {} \;

don't forget to follow the steps in other answers to commit and add gitignore.