# Removing folders in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I uploaded a Eclipse project to a BitBucket repository. I can see that Eclipse project in the BitBucket but I want to completely remove it from the BitBucket repository (without having to completely delete the repository and create a new repository). How do I remove this project? I am sorry I am git and bitbucket noob

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .pyc files from Git remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021040/remove-pyc-files-from-git-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Use **git rm** to remove old folder

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace the bitbucket repository with a new one .
make a new local repository . add the remote and run this command

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

it will replace the history on bitbucket with the new one.
also if you have created branches, you would want to [delete them](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html)